# What might prevent mouse movements between xrandr screens?

Tags: 10.04, mouse, xrandr, displaylink

I've followed the steps outlined in this [HowTo](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1493143).

Right after I log in to Gnome I can move the mouse back and forth but as soon as the task bar loads, the mouse becomes jailed in the screen its in (can't move between screens).

This is my xorg.conf:

```
 Section "ServerLayout"
            Identifier     "Layout0"
            Screen      0  "DisplayLinkScreen" 0 0
            Screen   1  "Screen0" LeftOf "DisplayLinkScreen"
            InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
            InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
            Option     "Xinerama" "0" #Could not get this to work it has to be disable
EndSection

Section "Files"
 ModulePath   "/usr/local/lib/xorg/modules/drivers"
 ModulePath      "/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers"
 ModulePath      "/usr/local/lib"

 ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
 FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
 FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
 FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
 FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
 FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
 FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
 FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
 FontPath     "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType"
 FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
 Load  "dbe"
 Load  "dri"
 Load  "dri2"
 Load  "extmod"
 Load  "glx"
 Load  "record"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
 Identifier  "Keyboard0"
 Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
 Identifier  "Mouse0"
 Driver      "mouse"
 Option     "Protocol" "auto"
 Option      "Device" "/dev/psaux" 
 # Option     "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
 Option     "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
 Identifier   "Monitor0"
 VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
 ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "NoAccel"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SWcursor"            # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ColorKey"            # <i>
        #Option     "CacheLines"          # <i>
        #Option     "Dac6Bit"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DRI"                 # [<bool>]
        #Option     "NoDDC"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ShowCache"           # [<bool>]
        #Option     "XvMCSurfaces"        # <i>
        #Option     "PageFlip"            # [<bool>]
 Identifier  "Card0"
 Driver      "intel"
 VendorName  "Intel Corporation"
 BoardName   "Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller"
 BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
 Option     "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
 Identifier "Screen0"
 Device     "Card0"
 Monitor    "Monitor0"
 SubSection "Display"
  Viewport   0 0
  Depth     1
 EndSubSection
 SubSection "Display"
  Viewport   0 0
  Depth     4
 EndSubSection
 SubSection "Display"
  Viewport   0 0
  Depth     8
 EndSubSection
 SubSection "Display"
  Viewport   0 0
  Depth     15
 EndSubSection
 SubSection "Display"
  Viewport   0 0
  Depth     16
 EndSubSection
 SubSection "Display"
  Viewport   0 0
  Depth     24
 EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "DisplayLinkMonitor"
EndSection
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "DisplayLinkDevice"
    Driver  "displaylink"
    Option   "fbdev" "/dev/fb0"
EndSection
Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "DisplayLinkScreen"
    Device          "DisplayLinkDevice"
    Monitor         "DisplayLinkMonitor"
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes       "1920x1200" "1920x1080" "1680x1050" "1600x1200" "1440x900" "1366x768" "1280x1024" "1280x960" "1280x800"  "1280x768"  "1152x864" "1024x768" "800x600" "640x480" 
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm so close to getting this to work!

Comment: @Tim

Good luck my friend. I still haven't gotten it to work. Hopefully the driver gods will smile upon you.

Answer (score 6):

My best guess here is that the position of the right screen is causing the problems. You could try modifying the ServerLayout section like this:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier     "Layout0"
        Screen         0 "Screen0" 0 0
        Screen         1 "DisplayLinkScreen" RightOf "Screen0"
        InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
        InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
        Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection
```

Or if you really want the DisplayLinkScreen to be the primary screen, modify it so that the coordinates match the resolution of Screen0. For example Screen0 has resolution 1900x1200:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier     "Layout0"
        Screen         0  "DisplayLinkScreen" 1900 0
        Screen         1  "Screen0" LeftOf "DisplayLinkScreen"
        InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
        InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
        Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection
```

Another possible location for the problems could be in RandR configuration which gets loaded during gnome startup. You can completely reset the RandR configuration by deleting `~/.config/monitors.xml`.

Answer (score 4):

I found a tool [here](http://digamma.cs.unm.edu/trac.dmohr/wiki/DualscreenMouseUtils) that automatically wraps the mouse between separated screens.

It worked for me when I had trouble getting the mouse to move between screens.

Answer (score 2):

You've got two different graphics devices, one with -intel, one with -displayport, and want to stitch them together so the mouse moves seamlessly across them.  Xinerama is what stitches multiple screens together, so you need that enabled.

However, Xinerama mode for -intel is not really that well supported (should be getting better though).  Maybe you'll be lucky with it, but as far as I know it's not expected that this should work.

You probably can get it to work if you use the -nvidia proprietary binary driver though.